# Condition number for each variable

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Condition number of a matrix tells us how viable it is to solve $Ax=b$

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1.001&1\\
1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is a matrix that would be difficult to solve numerically.

However consider this matrix

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0 &0\\
0&1.001&1\\
0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It is equally difficult to solve for $x_2$ and $x_3$, however we can still numerically find $x_1$ very precisely. I am looking for an algorithm that can assign a 'condition value' for each variable. So if I inputted the second $A$ to that algorithm, it would tell me that the 'condition number' of the first variable is 1 but the second and third variables are 4000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could say this.  If $e_i$ is the $i$'th standard unit vector, 
and $A x = b$ with $A$ invertible, then $x_i = e_i^T x = e_i^T A^{-1} b$, so that

$$ \dfrac{|\delta x_i|/\|x\|}{\|\delta b\|/\|b\|} \le \|e_i^T A^{-1}\| \|A\|$$

Note that it makes some sense here to take $|\delta x_i|/\|x\|$, the error in $x_i$ relative to the whole vector $x$, rather than the error in $x_i$ relative to $x_i$ itself.

Comment: I have a question. If we consider the second example I give in my post, the value for the first variable turns out to be 2. Clearly there will be no error amplification for that value, so intuitively it should be 1. The 2 is caused by ||A||=2. What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 2):

such problem was analyzed in
Chandrasekaran, Shivkumar, and Ilse CF Ipsen. "On the sensitivity of solution components in linear systems of equations." SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications 16.1 (1995): 93-112.

One of the result from this paper:
If $(A+F)\bar{x} = b$ and $|F| \leq \epsilon |A|$, then the upper bound for relative forward error in i-th component of the solution is:
$$\frac{|\bar{x}_i - x_i|}{|x_i|} \leq \epsilon \frac{|e_i^TA^{-1}| |A| |\bar{x}|}{|x_i|}$$